# Travis CI android emulator can't be created with avdmanager

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-testing

I want to build and test an Android app using an emulator in Travis CI.

On my local machine I can create emulator with both `android` and `avdmanager` tools, examples:

```
echo no | android create avd --force --name test01 --package 'system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86'

echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name test02 --package 'system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86'
```

But on Travis there's no `avdmanager` in $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

[image]

When I tried to create emulator with `android` tool (which isn't desired because it's deprecated) it turned out that it's different from version installed on my mac and requires different parameters

[image]

My `.travis.yml` file (vars and build steps removed for clarity):

```
sudo: true
os: linux
dist: trusty
language: android

android:
  components:
  - build-tools-26.0.2
  - android-26

before_script:
- echo no | android create avd --force --name test --package 'system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86'
#- echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name test --package 'system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86'

script:
- echo "DEBUG searching for avdmanager" && ls -lAp $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
```

So could you please advice how should I create Android emulator in Travis CI?

Answer (score 4):

After playing around the official ways, the simplest way I found to launch one emulator on travis has at least this in `travis.xml`

```
before_install:
  # Install SDK license so Android Gradle plugin can install deps.
  - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
  - echo "d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" >> "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
  # Install the rest of tools (e.g. avdmanager)
  - sdkmanager tools
  # Install the system image.
  - sdkmanager "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a"
  # Create and start emulator for the script. Meant to race the install task.
  - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n emulatorApi24 -k "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd emulatorApi24 -no-audio -no-window &

before_script:
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  # Disable animations
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest # Run emulator tests
```

Now my travis build takes 20 minutes :D

As a reference, a good place to check a working example is the [U+2020 project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020).